# Android AOSP quickly rebuild system.img only

Tags: android-source

For Android AOSP build system. is it possible rebuild system.img from `out/target/prodcut/xx/` only?

I am studying Android AOSP, and build system. However the rebuild time is too long for me.
.for for example

`mm <module>`

Then the output should be like as `out/target/product/<xxx>/<vendor/system>/...`

Finally, I want to regenerate images from `out/target/product/<xxx>/` only to save time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following targets to only build the images (including the modules on which they are dependent).

- `systemimage` for `system.img`
- `vendorimage` for `vendor.img`
- `vbmetaimage` for `vbmeta.img`

[and many more](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/pie-release:build/make/core/main.mk;l=1064)

**Example:**

```
m systemimage
```

**Note:** This is only an incremental build and not a full rebuild. For a full rebuild you have to call `m clean` first.